# How to use PHP to return a count of images in a directory?

Tags: php, javascript

I have a Javascript object like this:

> ```
> var count = {
>             table:19,
>             people:39,
>             places_details:84,
>             story_1:18,
>             story_2:6,
>             story_3:11
>             }
> ```

Each item (table, people, etc.) is a directory ***within*** my `graphics/` directory at the site root. I would like to use PHP to supply the numeric values by counting the JPG images in the corresponding directory. I imagine something like this:

> ```
> ar count = {
>            table: <?php count(dir("table")) ?>,
>            people: <?php count(dir("people")) ?>,
>            places_details: <?php count(dir("places_details")) ?>,
>            story_1: <?php count(dir("story_1")) ?>,
>            story_2: <?php count(dir("story_2")) ?>,
>            story_3:<?php count(dir("story_3")) ?>
>            }
> ```

But need to filter for JPG and return a number. What's the right code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to count the number of jpg images in a directory you can do:

```
count(glob("dir/*.jpg"));
```

The [glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) function returns an array containing the matched files and then we use count on that array.

Comment: That's pretty cool. I've never heard of that function before, so I made my own style show below, but I would think that your answer is much more concise. So +1 to you sir.

Comment: `<?php count(glob("table/*.jpg")); ?>` returns nothing.
`<?php echo count(glob("table/*.jpg")); ?>` returns 0, despite there being 19 images in the directory. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you using the correct path, i.e. is the `table` directory in the same directory as your PHP script? Otherwise you could try an absolute path such as `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/graphics/table/*.jpg'`.

Comment: Is the file extension really `.jpg` or maybe `.JPG` or `.Jpg`? Mind the case-sensitivity of your file system.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use the [glob()](http://php.net/glob) function to retrieve all filenames ending in `.jpg` and count them.

If you want to make sure these are really JPEG files, you'll have to check them e. g. with [finfo_file()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php).

Comment: +1 for the checking the file is really what you want with finfo_file.

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_dir_structure($path, $recursive = TRUE, $ext = NULL)
{
    $return = NULL;
    if (!is_dir($path))
    {
        trigger_error('$path is not a directory!', E_USER_WARNING);
        return FALSE;
    }
    if ($handle = opendir($path))
    {
        while (FALSE !== ($item = readdir($handle)))
        {
            if ($item != '.' && $item != '..')
            {
                if (is_dir($path . $item))
                {
                    if ($recursive)
                    {
                        $return[$item] = get_dir_structure($path . $item . '/', $recursive, $ext);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $return[$item] = array();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if ($ext != null && strrpos($item, $ext) !== FALSE)
                    {
                        $return[] = $item;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }
    return $return;
}
```

Use that function to do this:

```
ar count = {
    table: <?php echo count(get_dir_structure("./graphics/table/", FALSE, '.jpg')) ?>,
    people: <?php echo count(get_dir_structure("./graphics/people/", FALSE, '.jpg')) ?>,
    places_details: <?php echo  count(get_dir_structure("./graphics/places_details/", FALSE, '.jpg')) ?>,
    story_1: <?php echo count(get_dir_structure("./graphics/story_1/", FALSE, '.jpg')) ?>,
    story_2: <?php echo count(get_dir_structure("./graphics/story_2/", FALSE, '.jpg')) ?>,
    story_3: <?php echo count(get_dir_structure("./graphics/story_3/", FALSE, '.jpg')) ?>
}
```